# Designing ActiveRecord models : User - Organization - Membership - Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mapping

I am new to Rails and designing an application where domain entities are related like:

- User belongs to many Organizations
- Organization have many Users
- Organization have many Applications
- Application is developed by an Organization
- Application is developed by many Users(developers) of same organization
- User is developer of many Applications

Here is the mapping of above relations

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :organizations, through: :memberships

    has_many :application_developers
    has_many :applications, through: application_developers
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :organization

    has_many :application_developers
    has_many :memberships, through: application_developers 
end

class ApplicationDeveloper < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :membership
    belongs_to :application
end
```

would anyone please verify if above mapping is correct? Please give your feedback.

It would be very appreciable if you have design better than above.

Answer (score 0):

If every user from the organization is not working on an app, and it is only certain users, then I would keep the ApplicationDeveloper table, but change

`belongs_to :membership`

to

`belongs_to :user`

Comment: based on your explanation, it didn't seem like there would only be certain users from each organization working on an application. If every user from the organization is not working on an app, and it is only certain users, then I would keep the ApplicationDeveloper table, but change belongs_to :membership to belongs_to :user

Comment: All developers to the Application are of same organization

Comment: are all developers in the organization ok to work on the application? if so, you don't need the table. If only some developers within the organization can use the application and some can't, then you need the table.